# Give label.Text in User Control new value at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, user-controls

I'm an apprentice learning c#. 
In my current project I must learn the basics about "User Control" and "Drag and Drop". As the topic for my project I have chosen to do a basic team administration tool for my favorite football team.

I thought, that I would load a players data/stats in a user control and add the user control to a flowlayoutpanel.

```
Players players = new Players();
foreach (Player player in players.GetActive())
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new UCPlayer(player.ImageKey,player.Number, player.Name, player.Position, player.Rating
}
```

Now, when the program tries to change the text of a label in the user control, I get the following exception: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

I'm used to make properties like this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But in the user control i did it like this:

```
public int Number
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(this.UCMLBNumber.Text); }
        set { this.UCMLBNumber.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

public string Name
    {
        get { return this.UCMLBName.Text; }
        set { this.UCMLBName.Text = value; }
    }
```

The exception occurs, when the compiler compiles the set part. (Yes, in every property done like the ones above)

I don't get, what i did wrong. Please help me. Just ask, if you need any additional information.

Edit: Additional informations

```
public UCPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ImageIndex = 0;
        this.Number = 0;
        this.Nname = string.Empty;
        this.Position = string.Empty;
        this.Rating = 0;
    }

        public UCPlayer(int _imageIndex, int _number, string _name, string _position, int _rating)
    {
        this.ImageIndex = _imageIndex;
        this.Number = _number;
        this.Nname = _name;
        this.Position = _position;
        this.Rating = _rating;
    }
```

Comment: where is UCMLBName defined?

Comment: idk if i got the question right. I defined it in the form designer(?).

Comment: Possibly you are getting/setting the properties before the controls are initialized. Show where you're setting them.

Comment: I'm so sorry but how can I find, what you asked for. English isn't my native language and I've never done something with user control.

Comment: Is this, what you meant? I did an edit.

Comment: Debug this project, Set a break point in your "Set" code, once the break point is hit, check if the control is null? If yes, that mean you are accessing them before they got initialized by the .net runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out, what the problem was. 
The constructor of a user control differs to one of a class. Every constructor in a user control needs "InitializeComponents();".

From:

```
public UCPlayer(int _imageIndex, int _number, string _name, string _position, int _rating)
    {
        this.ImageIndex = _imageIndex;
        this.Number = _number;
        this.Nname = _name;
        this.Position = _position;
        this.Rating = _rating;
    }
```

To:

```
public UCPlayer(int _imageIndex, int _number, string _name, string _position, int _rating)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ImageIndex = _imageIndex;
        this.Number = _number;
        this.Nname = _name;
        this.Position = _position;
        this.Rating = _rating;
    }
```

Thank you Rotem and Sunil.